# DBCC CheckDb - get sql messages in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dbcc

I am using this code to check my database for errors :

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKDB (offpoDb) WITH TABLERESULTS", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But, u see,  this command only generates SQL messages.

Is there any way to retrieve the messages in .net ? 

Can i show the messages in a `MessageBox` ?

I've studied [InfoMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) but i still fail to understand how to apply it/work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `SqlDataReader` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` to get the recordset returned by `TABLERESULTS`:

```vb
Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKDB (offpoDb) WITH TABLERESULTS", con)
    Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While reader.Read
        strBuilder.AppendLine(CStr(reader("MessageText")))
    End While

    reader.Close()
End Using

MessageBox.Show(strBuilder.ToString)
```

To see all columns which are returned, execute the query in SQL Server Management Studio.

If you prefer to use the [`InfoMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx)-event then add a handler and use it like following:

```vb
Sub MyMethod()
    Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("<yourConnectionString>")
        con.Open()

        AddHandler con.InfoMessage, AddressOf InfoMessage

        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKDB (offpoDb)", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub InfoMessage(sender As Object, e As SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
End Sub
```

Comment: hey, is my code the perfect solution for checking the db fot errors? are there better solutions??

Comment: @zackraiyan I've edited my answer and added an example with the `InfoMessage`-event. There may be other or better solutions. You have to decide which one is the perfect solution for you.

Comment: thanks...but i am okay with 1st solution...can u help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774263/dbcc-checkdb-any-ways-to-detect-errors-vb-net)