# DBCC CheckDb-any ways to detect errors vb.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dbcc

I am using the below code to check if my database has any issues/requires troubleshooting:

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKDB (offpoDb) WITH TABLERESULTS", con)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
executing.Content = "Checking datatabse for errors"
executing.Margin = New Thickness(243, 111, 0, 0)
While reader.Read
    strBuilder.AppendLine(CStr(reader("MessageText")))
End While
reader.Close()
MessageBox.Show(strBuilder.ToString)
```

Now, the `DBCC CHECKDB` command might result in something like this :

`CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 15 consistency errors in database 'mydb`

Which can be fixed the following SQL query :

```sql
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK 
IMMEDIATE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DBCC CHECKDB ('AdventureWorks2008R2', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 SET MULTI_USER;
```

But before executing the following query through my application, is there a way to know if `DBCC CHECKDB` has really returned any errors at all ? Because without any errors, repairing the database will be useless...

Any help ?

**AN IDEA THAT CROSSED MY MIND**

I was thinking of getting the string from `strBuilder` to a textbox.The textbox will be checked for the availability of the following line `CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 15 consistency errors in database`..

But this is still not possible because that line can be different from time to time.E.g.

`CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 15 consistency errors`

`CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 14 consistency errors`

Any better ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities:

**1.**

Add [`NO_INFOMSGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql) option to the command.
Like this, no records will be returned if no errors are found.

```sql
DBCC CHECKDB (dname) WITH TABLERESULTS, NO_INFOMSGS
```

---

**2.**

Read the value(s) of column `Level`. If one is higher than `10`, an error occured. ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities)) 
A list of the DBCC-errors you can get with:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.sysmessages 
WHERE description LIKE '%checkdb%' AND msglangid = 1033 AND severity > 10
```

---

**3.**

Check the result-string for a number higher than `0`.

```vb
For Each c As Char In "CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 15 consistency errors"
    If (Char.IsNumber(c)) AndAlso Integer.Parse(c) > 0 Then
        'Errors occured
    End If
Next
```